# Remove space of image in imagebutton in toolbar

Tags: android-toolbar, android-imagebutton

This my "toolbar_main.xml" file for use custom toolbar menu in every activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#ddFFFFFF">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_back"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_app_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Image Status"
            android:textAppearance="?
            android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am using svg image for image button which is use for custom back press button. Problem is Relativelayout put some space on left side.

[Screenshot of toolbar_main.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbbQl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put,

```
 app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
 app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

in your Toolbar.

for eg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#ddFFFFFF">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_back"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_app_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Image Status"
            android:textAppearance="?
            android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add XML attributes to your Toolbar to remove content insets.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#ddFFFFFF"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
```